# Error: Endpoint auth data not present: undefined

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, packer, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to run the packer image .json file with azure devops pipeline but on packer job it is prompting the following error.
[Error: Endpoint auth data not present: undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9EY3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hit this error when the service connection details where missing from the `Packer` task in the Azure Devops pipline.   In my case I was using a variable that was undefined like so:

```yaml
- task: Packer@1
  inputs:
    connectedServiceType: 'azure'
    azureSubscription: '$(INVALID_VARIABLE_HERE)'
    ...
```

In this case I had to make sure the variable referenced my service connection name.